# Web site glitching on one page, where the rest of the pages are fine

Tags: html

I have my website with all the pages with a layout for each page that resembles this: 
http://gyazo.com/401996f65b68b95b9a26d560a3f7699e

However there is one page that appears glitched and it looks like this:
http://gyazo.com/b35c576f57029a1872fe6420afff6060

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this issue?

Here is the code:

HTML for that glitched page:

```
<head>
    <title>CRAFT412 - Rules</title>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>
<!--HTML FOR ALL PAGES-->
<!--BODY SECTION-->

<body>
    <!--WRAPPER SECTION-->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!--TOP BANNER SECTION-->
        <div id="banner">
            <div id="logo">
                <center>
                    <img src="images/CRAFT412 - Logo.png" width="500" height="100" />
                </center>
            </div>
            <div id="ip">
                 <h4>SERVER IP: 82.31.216.149:25565</h4>

            </div>
            <div id="teamspeak_logo"> <a href="ts3server://82.31.216.149:9987">
                                                              <img src="images/CRAFT412 -Teamspeak logo.png" width="136" height="40"/></a>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!--TOP NAV BAR SECTION-->
        <div id="nav_bar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="status.html">STATUS</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="info.html">INFO</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">GAMEMODES</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="gamemodessurvival.html">SURVIVAL</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">PURE-PVP</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">GAMESWORLD</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="rules.html">RULES</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="vote.html">VOTE</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--RULES CONTENT-->
         <h3>RULES</h3>

         <h3><br>GLOBAL RULES</h3>

        <p>Global rules follow across the entire server</p>
        <p>All players are expected to comply to all of the listed rules or they will be muted, kicked, timed out or banned</p>
         <h4>Rule listing:</h4>

        <li>No griefing
            <li>No flying. (Unless you've been given a high enough rank)
                <li>No unauthorized mod usage
                    <li>No hacked clients
                        <li>No cheating
                            <li>Show all other players respect. Including staff
                                <li>No begging for rank
                                    <p>All rules are enforced by staff in a strict manner</p>
                                     <h4>Punishments can include:</h4> 
                                    <li>Privilages taken away
                                        <li>Mutes
                                            <li>Prison (Survival)
                                                <li>Temporary bans
                                                    <li>Permanent bans
                                                        <li>IP bans
                                                             <h3><br>SURVIVAL RULES</h3>

                                                             <h4>Rule listing:</h4> 
                                                            <li>Global rules
                                                                <li>Don't build to close to other peoples creations, keep a reasonable distance
                                                                    <li>No begging for materials
                                                                        <!--HTML FOR ALL PAGES-->
                                                                        <!--BOTTOM FOOTER SECTION-->
                                                                        <div id="bottom_footer">
                                                                            <div id="created_by">
                                                                                <center>2014 © GR412</center>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div id="social_media_youtube"> <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/GR412" target="_blank">
                                                                           <img src="images/CRAFT412 - YouTube Button.png" width="40" height="40"/></a>

                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div id="social_media_twitch"> <a href="http://www.twitch.tv/gr412" target="_blank">
                                                                          <img src="images/CRAFT412 - Twitch Button.png" width="35" height="35"/></a>

                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div id="social_media_twitter"> <a href="https://twitter.com/GR412" target="_blank">
                                                                           <img src="images/CRAFT412 - Twitter Button.png" width="55" height="55"/></a>

                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div id="social_media_facebook"> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/GR412" target="_blank">
                                                                            <img src="images/CRAFT412 - Facebook Button.png" width="45" height="40"/></a>

                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And this CSS for all the pages:

```
    /*CSS FOR ALL PAGES*/

/*ID SELECTIONS SECTION*/

/*BODY/WRAPPER SECTION*/
 body {
    background-color:black;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
}
/*TOP BANNER SECTION*/
 #banner {
    background-color:black;
}
#logo {
    padding-top:27px;
    margin :-27px;
}
#ip {
    color:white;
    float:right;
}
/*TOP NAV BAR SECTION*/
 #nav_bar {
    background-color: #a22b2f;
    padding:1px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px;
    height:45px;
}
#nav_bar ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav_bar ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#nav_bar ul li ul {
    display: none;
}
#nav_bar>ul>li>a:hover {
    background:#8c1b1f;
    padding-bottom:12px;
    padding-top:16px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
#nav_bar>ul>li>ul>li>a:hover {
    background:#c9c9c9;
    padding-bottom:2px;
    padding-top:2px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
#nav_bar ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #e2e2e2;
    padding-top:1px;
    padding-bottom:1px;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#nav_bar ul li:hover ul li {
    display: block;
}
#nav_bar ul li:hover ul li a {
    color: black;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin-left:-15px;
}
/*BOTTOM FOOTER SECTION*/
 #bottom_footer {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#e2e2e2;
    margin-top:40px;
    border-top:solid 10px black;
    border-bottom:solid 3px black;
}
#created_by {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    margin:17px;
}
#social_media_youtube {
    float:left;
    margin:-47px;
    margin-left:275px;
}
#social_media_twitch {
    float:left;
    margin:-44px;
    margin-left:335px;
}
#social_media_twitter {
    float:right;
    margin:-53px;
    margin-right:320px;
}
#social_media_facebook {
    float:right;
    margin:-47px;
    margin-right:280px;
}
/*ELEMENT SELECTIONS SECTION*/
 p {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
}
li {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-left:20px;
}
h2 {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h3 {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-left:20px;
}
h4 {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-left:20px;
}
/*CSS FOR SPECIFIC PAGES*/

/*CLASS SELECTIONS SECTION*/

/*VOTE PAGE*/
 .vote_button {
    margin-left:20px;
}
/*STATUS PAGE*/
 .status {
    margin:20px;
}
/*INFO PAGE*/
 .gallery_thumbnails img {
    height: 60px;
    width: 106px;
    padding: 1px;
}
.gallery_thumbnails img:hover {
    border: 3px solid #a22b2f;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.gallery_preview img {
    padding: 1px;
}
.gallery_thumbnails {
    position: relative;
}
.imagebox {
    display: inline;
}
.text {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    left:140px;
    top: -30px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.imagebox img:hover + .text {
    display: block;
}
/*SPECIFIC PAGES ID SELECTIONS SECTION*/

/*INDEX/GAMEMODE PAGES*/
 #banner_image {
    padding-top:30px;
}
```

[JSFiddle of this page](http://jsfiddle.net/vy447hqo/)

Comment: First, run your code through a validator and close all those unclosed tags. If you don't close your tags, the browser has to guess where you meant to close them... and browsers don't always guess right.

Comment: Can you also specify what is wrong with the page, and what you've done to try to fix it? E.g. commented out sections of the code, etc. It is difficult to tell what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is pretty messy and needs quite a bit of cleaning up. You have list tags that are not closed all over the place, you have them nested in divs and they must be nested in ul tags(which you have correct in part of the html), your line break tags need to be self closed(add a / after the br as below)...

```
<ul> <!--You need the ul tags around your li tags... -->
    <li>List Item 1</li> <!-- Close the tags... -->
    <li>List Item 2</li> 
    <li>List Etc...</li>
</ul> <br /> <!-- Proper BR tags are self-closing
```

Didn't see anything else that seemed out of place but with so many open tags it's hard to tell without fixing them all first.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm very new to coding so I make lot's of common noobish mistakes.

Comment: `<br>` tags only need to be self closed if an `XHTML` doctype is used to validate